# macos extended attributes xattr -d not removing extended attributes

Tags: macos, file-attributes

For a simple local file owned by myself the following is having no effect:

```
1:37:51/spark-training-scripts:113 $ll  /shared/sparkeast.pem
-rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  1692 Mar  7 11:30 /shared/sparkeast.pem
```

Let us view the extended attributes:

```
11:44:00/spark-training-scripts:114 $xattr /shared/sparkeast.pem
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.quarantine
```

Attempt to delete the extended attributes (all of them):

11:44:24/spark-training-scripts:115 $xattr -d /shared/sparkeast.pem

No change:

```
11:44:28/spark-training-scripts:116 $xattr /shared/sparkeast.pem
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.quarantine
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xattr -d` will delete a single attribute, and you must specify the attribute name:

```
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms /shared/sparkeast.pem
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /shared/sparkeast.pem
```

Alternately, you can use `xattr -c`, which clears all extended attributes from the file:

```
xattr -c /shared/sparkeast.pem
```