# How to clear (remove) macos extended attributes recursively from a directory?

Tags: command-line, mac, file-attributes

I downloaded and extracted an archive from GitHub ([Homebrew/brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew)) into a temporary directory under `/root` (with help from `sudo`). If I do `ls -l` I see an extended attribute:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 root  wheel  512 Jul  2 09:30 brew-master
```

If I do `ls -l@` (thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/155459/567758) to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal)) I get the following output:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 root  wheel  512 Jul  2 09:30 brew-master
    com.apple.quarantine     59
```

If I do `ls -l@ brew-master` I get the following output:

```
total 48
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel    98 Jul  2 09:30 CHANGELOG.md
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel  3161 Jul  2 09:30 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   720 Jul  2 09:30 CONTRIBUTING.md
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel  1334 Jul  2 09:30 LICENSE.txt
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
drwxr-xr-x@  7 root  wheel   224 Jul  2 09:30 Library
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel  7374 Jul  2 09:30 README.md
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel    96 Jul  2 09:30 bin
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   160 Jul  2 09:30 completions
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
drwxr-xr-x@ 48 root  wheel  1536 Jul  2 09:30 docs
    com.apple.quarantine      59 
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   160 Jul  2 09:30 manpages
    com.apple.quarantine      59
```

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/825647/567758) to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/825552/how-to-remove-mac-extended-attributes-from-a-file) tells me to do `xattr -d` to clear the attribute but it would only work on a single file or directory entry.

How can I clear this attribute recursively?

P.S. If I would unzip the download into a non-root subdirectory I seem to get a similar quarantine attribute.

Answer (score 10):

Quick and easy solution (combination of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/726122/567758) to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/726112/macos-extended-attributes-xattr-d-not-removing-extended-attributes) and [this blog post](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications/)):

```
xattr -cr brew-master
```

(using `sudo` if and only if this is within root directory)

Slightly more refined solution from [the same blog post](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications/):

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine brew-master
```

An even better solution would be to use command-line tools to fetch and extract such an archive in order to avoid this kind of issue in the first place. This kind of solution is part of [my answer on how to install Homebrew manually](https://superuser.com/a/1336026/567758).

Comment: As of Sonoma 14, the option -r has been removed for some unexplained reason.

Comment: I noticed that on my Sonoma installation, the xattr in homebrew (/opt/bin/xattr) doesn't have the -r option but /usr/bin/xattr does. Hmmm.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to move the folder outside of ~/Downloads first, otherwise `com.apple.macl` was being reapplied to the file while processing it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without brew, this way:

```
xattr -r -d  com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms /Users/MyUserName/Downloads/FolderContainingFilesAndOtherFolders
```

To remove those datas from anything in a particular folder.